# How to read/write to many text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, writefile, writetofile

So in short, i have a directory that looks like

[image]

All the given text files look like

[image]

and I want to iterate through each file and input the text `This is file #i` at a certain line where `i` is the EXACT number of the file in its file name. I've watched countless videos on the `os` module, but still cant figure it out.

So just for reference,

[image]

is the goal im trying to reach for each file within the directory.

Comment: Please include the details in the question itself as text if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
indirpath = 'path/to/indir/'
outdirpath = 'path/to/outdir/'
files = os.listdir(indirpath)
inp_pos = 2 # 0 indexed line number where you want to insert your text

for file in files:
    name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]     # get file name by removing extension
    inp_line = f'This is file #{name}'    # this is the line you have to input
    lines = open(os.path.join(indirpath, file)).read().strip().split('\n')
    lines.insert(min(inp_pos, len(lines)), inp_line) # insert inp_line at required position

    with open(os.path.join(outdirpath, file), 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

You can have `indirpath` and `outdirpath` as the same if your goal is to overwrite the original files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple approach of reading the lines, modifying them and writing back. This is good enough if your files are not very large.
An eg.

```
def process_file(file, insert_index):
    file_lines = []
    # read the lines in file
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        file_lines = f.readlines()

    # insert the new line and write back to file
    with open(file, "w") as f:
        file_lines.insert(insert_index, f"This is file #{file.stem}\n")
        f.writelines(file_lines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from glob import glob
    import pathlib

    files = glob('./test/*.txt')  # list your files in the folder
    [process_file(pathlib.Path(file), 2) for file in files]  # Update each file in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
folder_path = "you_folder"
row_you_expected_to_insert = 2

for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
    front_part = ""
    after_part = ""
    with open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name), "r+") as f:
        for i in range(1,row_you_expected_to_insert):
            # read until the place you want to insert
            front_part += f.readline()
        after_part = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(front_part)
        f.write(f"This is file #{file_name.split('.')[-2]}\n")
        f.write("".join(after_part))
```